# Unable to submit data via form

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple form:

```
<form ng-submit='addMessage()'>
    <input type='text' ng-model='chatMessage' placeholder='chat here' />
    <input type='submit' value='chat' />
</form>
```

And at the moment, a very simple function:

```
$scope.addMessage = function() {
    console.log($scope.chatMessage);
}
```

The console logging is just logging undefined, no matter what I type into the input box. Clearly I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: Can you share more code? Eg. is your form in a modal or anything?

Comment: Are you using get or post request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the way forms are used, sometimes `$scope` is out of context between the controller on the form. This is because `addMessage()`, and `chatMessage` are not on the same level of the `$scope` hierarchy.

One way to fix this is to create a container for your form items:

```
$scope.cont = {};
$scope.addMessage = function() {
    console.log($scope.cont.chatMessage);
}
```

And in the form:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="cont.chatMessage" placeholder="chat here"/>
```

This is also something you should definitely read if you are going to use angular more: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html

Comment: This was it. Never knew about this in angular, I'm just learning at the moment. The way I was doing it (the wrong way) worked for a previous form I did, so I just kept doing it. Thanks for this, and the link.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<form ng-submit='addMessage(chatMessage)'>
   <input type='text' ng-model='chatMessage' placeholder='chat here' />
   <input type='submit' value='chat' />
</form>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.addMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}
```

**UPDATE**

based on your comments i think you are looking for something like this:

```
        $scope.messages = [];

        $scope.$watch('messages', function(newMessage) {
            alert('hey, a message was added ! :' +newMessage);
        }, true);

        $scope.addMessage = function(msg) {
            $scope.messages.push(msg);
        };
```

Angular has so called watches, the watched function will trigger everytime when a new message is addded to the array. For more information about watches refer to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)

Comment: This did work, however, it breaks the link between my javascript code and my form.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't break it, it was already broken, but this doesn't fix it. I can't erase the value in the input box from the function for example. I gets the data to my function, but that's it.

Comment: I changed my answer based on your comments

Comment: I already had an answer that worked for my needs. But I appreciate the link and comment about "watches", didn't know about them either. I've learned a ton so far about angular, probably much more to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Look for that **[fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/LvKUC/)** maybe you missed something different .

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<form ng-submit='addMessage()'>
    <input type='text' ng-model='chatMessage' placeholder='chat here' />
    <input type='submit' value='chat' />
</form>
        <pre>{{msg | json}}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope) {

    $scope.msg = [];

    $scope.addMessage = function () {

        $scope.msg.push($scope.chatMessage);
        console.log($scope.chatMessage);
        $scope.chatMessage = "";


    }

});
```